GetX reactive bool listen with conditional widget adding
I have a reactive bool. Now if that is true I show a widget , but in case that is false then I don't need to show anything at all in that place.
As of now I am adding a Empty Container() or SizedBox.shrink() if the bool is false. Is there any way to not adding any Widget at all?
Example :
Obx(() {
  if (rxBool.value)) {
    return Positioned(
      right: 45.0,
      bottom: constraints.maxHeight / 4 + 85,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => controller.toggleTooltip(),
        child: SomeWidgetIWantToShow(),
      ),
    );
  }
  return const SizedBox.shrink();
})

in this how can I avoid return const SizedBox.shrink(); when rxBool.value == false

If the widget is child of a parent that as several children, like a Column or Row you can easily insert if statements within the list of children. Like this for example
Column(children: [
  SomeWidget(),
  SomeOtherWidget(),
  if (myBool) ConditionalWidget(),
  LastWidget(),
],)


EDIT:
If your code is something like this:
Column(children: [
  SomeWidget(),
  SomeOtherWidget(),
  Obx((){
    if (rxBool.value) {
      return Positioned(
        right: 45.0,
        bottom: constraints.maxHeight / 4 + 85,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => controller.toggleTooltip(),
          child: SomeWidgetIWantToShow(),
        ),
      );
    }
    return const SizedBox.shrink();
  }),
  LastWidget(),
],)

you can make it this instead
  Obx(()=>
    Column(children: [
      SomeWidget(),
      SomeOtherWidget(),
      if (rxBool.value)  Positioned(
        right: 45.0,
        bottom: constraints.maxHeight / 4 + 85,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => controller.toggleTooltip(),
          child: SomeWidgetIWantToShow(),
        ),
      ),
      LastWidget(),
    ],),
  )


I added example for clarity please check.

@KoustuvGanguly I'm assuming that Obx is child of maybe a Column or Row. Then wrap that Column/Row in an Obx instead and use my solution

@KoustuvGanguly I gave an example using your example

Thanks, but in my case it's inside Stack , I did as you said using Stack in place of Column(needed for impl) but never received the callback. Also my Scaffold is under Obx{}. So, used individual Obx().

@KoustuvGanguly no idea why it doesn't work then. I would think it should work

I was wrong. It works. Thanks!

If i not misunderstanding you want to hide it without using condition you can use Visibility to hide your widget but for conditional widget just do like @Ivo Answer
Visibility(
  visible:  // bool,
  child:  child //widget,
),

EDIT
Obx(
  () => Visibility(
    child: Positioned(
      right: 45.0,
      bottom: constraints.maxHeight / 4 + 85,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => controller.toggleTooltip(),
        child: Container(),
      ),
    ),
  ),


I added example for clarity please check.

This method work if you just want to avoid using SizedBox.shrink() or Container()

or you can do like @ivo answer it gonna work as well
